# How to extract multiple values (number or name) in String using Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium-ide

I have text displayed in my application that
"showing 1 - 20 of 25 records"

Here `20` and `25` are value of variables '`x`' and '`y`'. I need to extract these values of variable from message displayed on web application using Selenium IDE. 
Need to store `20` and `25` separately.

closely related to [this question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/16930/extract-value-of-variable-in-string-in-selenium-ide)

Comment: Just curious: which class is this for?

Comment: application shows table database record against set filter. and writes "showing 1 - 20 of 25 records".
I need to store these three numbers separately in different variable or array (preferable) , so that i can use them for loop or if condition. 
any help is appreciable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this steps :

```
<tr>
    <td>storeText</td>
    <td>//h1[@class='abc']</td>
    <td>k</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${k}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>storedVars['k'].substring(storedVars['k'].lastIndexOf('- ')+2,storedVars['k'].lastIndexOf(' of'))</td>
    <td>x</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${x}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>storedVars['k'].substring(storedVars['k'].lastIndexOf('of ')+2,storedVars['k'].lastIndexOf(' records'))</td>
    <td>y</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${y}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Here I have used `//h1[@class='abc']` element for taking its text. You can modify it.

Let me know If any queries.